# Python - Case Insensitive User Input For a Tuple

Tags: python, discord.py, case-insensitive

For example, I'm programming a Discord bot, and I want it to read certain keywords that a user might type and then for it to output a response. I have a list of keywords for the bot to read, but I want to have it be case insensitive.

```
angy_words = ["furious", "rage", "angry", "mad", "angy", "hate", "hatred", "so upset", "so mad", "lame", "loven't", "lord have mercy"]

if any(word in msg for word in angy_words): 
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(angy_response))
```

I've tried .lower(), .upper(), .casefold(), but I guess I'm not sure how/where to implement it. I haven't found any other answers/other online resources about doing this with tuple.

Thanks so much!

Comment: There is no tuple anywhere in your code. That said: you know how - according to the research you say you've already done - the way you compare two strings against each other case-insensitively is to put them both in the same case first, then compare? Well, now you want to compare one string against many strings, so for each of those comparisons... you just want them to be in the same case, right? Now, if every string in your `angy_words` is lowercase, does that suggest something you can do with the `msg` in order to get comparable values?

Comment: yes, you're totally right! I messed up an put one of my lists of strings in [()] instead of in just brackets, so the error message was saying I couldn't use msg.lower() on it. Stupid mistake that I didn't notice until I really thought about it and another answer pointed out that my mistake was somewhere else in my code rather than the posted bit. Thank you, I appreciate your time Karl!!

Comment: Ah well see, if you'd shown the specific attempt with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then you either would have fixed the problem while setting that up, or we could have pointed out the typo for you. :)

Comment: yes that is very true! I just thought the problem was with the excerpt here, rather than somewhere else. My bad! next time I will try testing only the excerpt instead of within my whole program

Answer (score 1):

as you were saying `lower()` will work here:

```
>>> x = "AaBbcC"
>>> x.lower()
'aabbcc'
```

So in your case (since the `list` is already lowercase):

```
any(word in msg.lower() for word in angy_words)
```

To avoid converting the message to lowercase multiple times:

```
lower_msg = msg.lower()
any(word in lower_msg  for word in angy_words)
```

Comment: You've made a mistake somewhere else. I just tested the answer again, and it works fine here. Double check your attributes, and that msg is indeed just the string, not some other object

Comment: Okay thank you so much I appreciate your time

edit: I found out I put () around a tuple instead of just leaving it in brackets. My bad!! You're amazing!!